# Why does glucose react with hydroxyl amine and HCN but doesn't give Schiff's test or react with NaHSO3?

Tags: biochemistry, carbohydrates

I can't understand this because if there isn't a free CHO group then it also shouldn't react with NH2OH and HCN.
On the same note can anyone also explain why pentaacetate of glucose not react with NH2OH? Why isn't there a free CHO in this case?

Comment: Look at the structure. There is a hemiacetal which does a lot of the same reactions as an aldehyde group. This is why glucose reacts with Hydroxylamine and HCN as cyanide and hydroxylamine are both very good nucloephile. Sulfite is, by comparison, a much poorer nucleopphile.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now. I believe in the pentaacetate form there is no free OH group to make it an aldehyde and therefore it doesn't react with hydroxylamine. Can you correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: You are correct see - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22269/does-glucose-react-with-bradys-reagent

Comment: Alright thank you 